# cannot run nativescript 'groceries' sample on android

Tags: nativescript

when try to run 'groceries' sample from http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1 I get a 'javaproxy is not defined error'

when I run 'tns run android' on console I get those warning in yellow:

```
nativescript-intl 1.7.0 for android is not compatible with the currently installed framework version 1.6.3.
tns-core-modules 2.0.0 for android is not compatible with the currently installed framework version 1.6.3.
tns-core-modules-widgets 2.0.0 for android is not compatible with the currently installed framework version 1.6.3.
```

seems that I have to update (or downgrade) some stuff, but not sure if have to use npm install --save module@version or what I can do, I'm new to all this stuff. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your nativescript version to the most recent release ( at least > 2.0.x ). So to do this, run `npm install nativescript -g`. However, you might still not get the desired functionality, as your dependancies might not be up to date also.

If that is the case, run this:

On Windows:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/production/setup/native-script.ps1'))"
```

On OSX:

```
sudo ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/production/setup/native-script.rb)"
```

If you have any issues with that, please refer too [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript) guide.

Comment: this time the yellow text with warning not show anymore, but I see too much times a text that says "up to date", and seems that it not "recompile", can I force "tns run android --emulator" commando to recompile to see if not it can work? 

if I have to post another query to this problem sorry for asking on a comment, thanks in advance

Comment: @FabianSilva that sounds like a separate issue and I think this one is resolved. Do post a link to the new question and I'll take a look :)

Comment: thanks you so much, I downloaded exampleto follow nativescript.org tutorial again and all was good, I can now start learning about nativescript :)

Comment: @FabianSilva awesome! I hope you like it :D Be sure to join the slack [channel](https://nativescriptcommunity.slack.com/messages/general/) if you need any more help.